# Set default text editor in Preferred Applications in MATE

Tags: text-editors, mate, neovim

I'm using [neovim-gtk](https://github.com/Lyude/neovim-gtk/) as my text editor, which I've compiled myself.  I'd like to set it as the default text editor in MATE's Preferred Applications, but there's no such option.

There is a desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications/org.daa.NeovimGtk.desktop`, which contains the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=NeovimGtk
Comment=Gtk GUI for Neovim text editor
Exec=/home/bmc/.local/bin/nvim-gtk -- %F
Icon=org.daa.NeovimGtk
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=GTK;Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
```

Note that I'm already capable of setting this in `EDITOR` and `VISUAL`, where it works fine.  However, opening the file from a MATE application, such as Engrampa, still invokes the default specified in the Preferred Applications window.

In case it's relevant, I'm using Debian unstable, but I'm also interested in responses for Ubuntu 23.10, both using MATE.

How should I go about configuring things so that I can set my preferred editor in the Preferred Applications window?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that what's required is running `update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications`.  Note that the specific directory is required because otherwise `update-desktop-database` attempts to update the system databases instead, which isn't relevant here and has no effect on per-user configuration.

Running this command creates or updates the `mimeinfo.cache` file, which is required for GTK+ to be able to look up a desktop file by MIME type.  GTK+ can still find the desktop file without it, but it's unable to perform searches by MIME type without this the `mimeinfo.cache` file, and MATE's Preferred Applications tool finds text editors by looking for files that support the MIME type `text/plain`.